# Run mjml cli using symfony process

Tags: php, laravel, symfony

I've installed mjml cli using the following command (as described in the mjml documentation):

```
npm install mjml --save
```

now if i did `node_modules/.bin/mjml` in the command line it will run successfully.

the problem is when i use the symfony process component in php i got the following error (even if it's the right path):

```
The command "/Users/qoraiche/Documents/my-app/node_modules/.bin/mjml" failed. Exit Code: 127(Command not found) Working directory: /Users/qoraicheOS/Documents/my-app/public Output: ================ Error Output: ================ env: node: No such file or directory
```

Symfony process code:

```
$process = new Process(base_path('node_modules/.bin/mjml'));

$process->run();

if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
    throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
}

echo $process->getOutput();
```

By the way i have installed mjml globally as well and try it with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try providing the full path to node.js when calling the MJML binary from a Symfony `Process()`.

```
$process = new Process('/your/path/to/node ' . base_path('node_modules/.bin/mjml'));
```

I use this method in my own apps.  Of course, you will need to provide the input and output files to actually transpile anything.